# How Can I call nested function in function?

Tags: function, swift, nested

I have a program like that

```
func Mom(){
    func isCalledFunc(){
    }
    //some code
    isCalledFunc()
}
```

But Swift whow Error. How can I call nested function in function? Thank

Comment: You have to call it within a method for it to be in the correct scope or from an instance of the Mom class ie. `someMom.isCalledFunct()`

Comment: I copied the code to Playground and it compiles fine. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is about OOP. You only can call the function from method of Object